# Audio starts playing 3-5 seconds after video does

Tags: sound, multimedia, displayport

I've installed Ubuntu Studio 16.04.1 LTS on my pc (ASRock X99 Taichi, i7 6800k, GTX 970, DisplayPort to iMac as monitor), my first experience with Ubuntu/Linux. I haven't installed any third party software during installation.

Whenever I play videos on youtube, the first 3-5 seconds are mute. If I pause and start playing the video from the beginning a second time, then the audio starts playing at the start. This happens every time I open a new video. Everything is in sync, but the audio always takes time to start playing. How can I fix this annoying glitch/delay? I am using the default Ubuntu Studio xfce desktop environment.

Comment: Have you tried to install Google Chrome to see if it does the same behaviour ?

Comment: Oooh, not yet. I'm going to try now.

Comment: ok, try do that and see if it helps. :)

Comment: Just tried with Chrome. Same exact thing, audio playback is delayed for 5 seconds :/

Comment: Can't remember this happening in over 4 years of using Ubuntu but it started happening about a month ago in both Youtube and Flashplayer where sound is delayed for a few seconds after video starts.

Answer (score 10):

### Perfect solution for specific problem, but not all applications

This solution works when pausing and resuming from the same sound source such as a movie:

Edit Pulse Audio configuration file: `sudo -H gedit /etc/pulse/default.pa`

Locate this section and place `#` in front of second line:

```
### Automatically suspend sinks/sources that become idle for too long
# load-module module-suspend-on-idle
```

Save the file and exit.

Reload Pulse Audio using `pulseaudio -k`.

### Where it doesn't work.

Whilst watching a movie I can have [laundry timer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039357/a-timer-to-set-up-different-alarms-simultaneosly/1039377#1039377) running in the background. When a alert sounds to signal end of Wash Cycle, Rinse Cycle or Dryer no sound is heard. The alert sound was < 5 seconds. The workaround is to pick a different sound file > 5 seconds long.

Comment: This module can also be unloaded with `pactl unload-module module-suspend-on-idle` command.

Answer (score 0):

My sound would take anywhere from 5 seconds to a minute before it would come on. Only on Firefox and going to YouTube. I tried everything on every forum. What turned out to be the problem for me was Firefox had a security and privacy setting set to block all video and audio. I turned the setting to allow all video and audio. No more problems....so far.