# Audio takes a second or 2 to start Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: nvidia, sound, 19.04

Whenever there is no audio playing through my pc and I start it takes a few seconds usually about 3 to start playing the audio. For example if I click on a youtube video it will play normally then when it hits about the 3 second mark audio will come on. However if I am already playing audio lets say on spotify the audio starts straight away. It seems to be only when it goes from have no audio.

The audio is playing through DisplayPort to my monitor from my GPU if that makes any difference.

System Specs in case its a hardware compatability issue:

- Mobo: Asus Z390f
- GPU: RTX 2980
- Monitor: LG Ultrawide 29UC88

If you want the full specs just message but I don't think anything else could cause the issue

Thanks

Comment: No it happens all over the system, If there is no audio then I start to play Spotify it will take a few seconds. It doesn't happen if I am playing games using Lutris but I'm not sure if that just because game audio takes a few seconds to start anyway to I'm just adding it to that

Comment: I am using the Spotify client for linux on snap. The web browser I am using is chrome but the same problem occurs if I am using firefox also. I am using Nvidia driver 418 installed through the "software and update" application. I am using the speakers built into my monitor that are coming through the display port cable, although what I have just figured out is if I go through the motherboard onboard graphics the issue doesn't seem to occur, so I think it is a 2000 series card bug.

Comment: This may be the solution to possibly the same issue: https://askubuntu.com/a/1089961/21029